# What punctuation should I use between a question and a bullet list?

Tags: punctuation

Posting in a StackExchange website, I was confronted to this situation:

Should I do it considering the following?

- condition 1
- condition 2
- ...

My first question is, was I right to use a question mark?

---

Plus, are other punctuations symbols allowed like colon and if so, when should I prefer it to a question mark?

Should I do it considering the following:

- condition 1
- condition 2
- ...

---

Finally, in another similar problem when I have:

Should I do it considering the following?

- case 1
- case 2
- ...

I'd say it's actually the same problem and what was said before remains, am I right?

Comment: I generally put a question mark followed by a colon. Would this work?:

Comment: Is it the only acknownledged way to do so? If yes you can answer my question :)

Comment: I would use either a question mark or a colon, but not both.  Some dialects still use multiple punctuation marks, but aside from one or two exceptions, I feel this is old-fashioned and generally redundant.  However, most of the time it does not matter much, unless you are writing for a formal publication.  In that case, consult their style guide to see if they have any specific rule.

Comment: @Andrew that would make a good answer

Comment: @Bee  sure, except that it's just one opinion of many.  Questions that can only be answered by opinions should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may get closed because it is opinion based, however to me there is a good answer that will always be right.

> Consider the following:
>
> - case 1
> - case 2
>
> Should I do it?